# Show users from same table where Sponser id equal to referral id of another user in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

How can I show users from the same table where Sponserid equal to referralid of another user in SQL query

| ID | NAME | SID | RID | TID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hsn | MLMM01 | Root | Root |
| 2 | Akash | MLMM02 | MLMM01 | MLMM01 |
| 3 | Abhi | MLMM03 | MLMM01 | MLMM01 |
| 4 | Somnath | MLMM04 | MLMM01 | MLMM01 |
| 5 | Sachin | MLMM05 | MLMM02 | MLMM02 |
| 6 | ashok | MLMM06 | MLMM02 | MLMM02 |
| 7 | raj | MLMM07 | MLMM02 | MLMM02 |
| 8 | manish | MLMM08 | MLMM03 | MLMM03 |
| 9 | lakhan | MLMM09 | MLMM03 | MLMM03 |
| 10 | ramesh | MLMM10 | MLMM03 | MLMM03 |
| 11 | shekhar | MLMM11 | MLMM04 | MLMM04 |
| 12 | rohit | MLMM12 | MLMM04 | MLMM04 |
| 13 | ashish | MLMM13 | MLMM04 | MLMM04 |

Comment: Please avoid posting image. use formatted text instead. Please show some sample data and expected result together with your current attempt and explain what is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can self join the table to achieve the purpose like:

```
SELECT  column_name(s)
FROM    table T1, table T2
WHERE   T1.SponserId = T2.Reffralid;
```

Comment: Yes @Rajan Patekar  but I have only one table and I want to join columns means 
I want to show users that have column_1 value and another user column_2 values are the same

Comment: Can you please share the table definition, some sample data, and expected result, so that, it will be easy for us to exercise and provide a solution?

Comment: you can see my table, i explain you .. like as you can see from my table .. user Akash have SID = MLMM02 and user Sachin have RID = MLMM02  ..then our condition is true and just want to show this both users after this condition is true ..

Comment: @AkashPise In that case the same solution works. We just need to provide column names with proper alias like T1.Name, T2.Name, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Akash!

I'd do the following using a Common Table Expression (CTE):

```
WITH referral_ids AS (
  SELECT 
    NAME,
    RID 
  FROM <table_name>)
)
SELECT 
  ri.NAME
FROM
  referral_ids AS ri
LEFT JOIN 
  <table_name> AS tn ON ri.RID = tn.SID
```

Comment: hii A CC  not working in my case showing this error 

Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Ambiguous column name 'Name'

Comment: hi there, @AkashPise! forgot to add the table alias in the query. Since there are two tables with the same column name, you need to specify the alias of the table to which you are referring the column. In this case, using ri.NAME will do the job :)